# How can I prepare a pie chart in excel with a result based on 100%?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts

I have the total I've earned last year which should represent the 100% of the pie.

Then I have my insurance expenses and I want to understand, graphically, how much of my total income went to pay insurance.

I know that a basic proportion like:

total expenses : total insurance costs = 100 : x

is the correct math but I can't find a way to display this in a pie chart.

Comment: ... you mean a "pie chart" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to make a pie chart correctly, you need to list the percentage for each item, and the sum of all these percentages must be equal to 1.

For example,

```
Total insurance cost: 0.2
Expense A: 0.4
Expense B: 0.3
Expense C: 0.1
```

Comment: You don't need to do the scaling yourself, the pie chart will do it for you